# Anchor tag inherits from unintended element

Tags: html, css, styling

I have piece of following code and a tags from header inherit a tag's styles from main.
I know that I can prevent it adding classes to each a tag, but is there any other way to solve it?

```css
    header li{
      display: inline-block;
    }
    header a:link, a:visited, a:active{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
    }
    header a:hover{
      color: #333;
    }
    
    main a:link, a:visited, a:active{
      color: #0ba39c;
    }
    main a:hover{
      color: #252525;
    }
```

```html
    <header>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">First element</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Second element</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </header>
    
    <main>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">First element</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Second element</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </main>
```

I also tried pointing it like: header > ul > li > a:link... but it doesn't work as well.
I saw on sites a lot of different styled anchors without additional classes, so I bet I am missing something.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Prevent a tags in header inherit styles from a tags in main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS comma combinator is used to list multiple individual selectors.

So instead of

```
header a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    ...
}
```

(which results in 3 selectors `header a:link`, `a:visited` and `a:active`)

the full selector for each link state has to be declared like so:

```
header a:link,
header a:visited,
header a:active {
    ...
}
```

(which results in 3 selectors `header a:link`, `header a:visited` and `header a:active`)

The same goes for `main`. I updated your example with distinguishable colors:

```css
    header li{
      display: inline-block;
    }
    header a:link,
    header a:visited,
    header a:active {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: red;
    }
    header a:hover{
      color: yellow;
    }
    
    main a:link,
    main a:visited,
    main a:active {
      color: green;
    }
    main a:hover{
      color: blue;
    }
```

```html
    <header>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">First element</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Second element</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </header>
    
    <main>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">First element</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Second element</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You and use their attribute to call a specific anchor tag in this manner

```
a[href="abc"]{
    /*your css property*/
}
```